# build from git repository and than clone another repository in a subfolder

Tags: jenkins

I've correctly setup jenkins to build my sources from my git repository and to deploy it using codedeploy plugin.
my project structure is the following :

```
main_folder
  |- subfolder1
  |- subfolder2
  |- subfolder3
```

at this point there's another subfolder called subfolder4 that is a cloned out from another git repository. 
Actually i clone the second repository from the script that codedeploy runs after installing the sources, but i'm facing issues with the ssh-key.
How can i configure jenkins to download subfolder4 content from another git repository ? thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Multiple SCMs Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multiple+SCMs+Plugin)

Allows your job to check out sources from multiple repository.

for the second repository just choose additional Behaviours -> check out to a sub-directory [image]